# How to add a Contact in Contact using iPhone Native UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, abaddressbook

I Want to add phone numbers in `Contact List` whenever user taps on a Phone Number.

I don't want to do it programatically in background and after saving just inform user.

I have recently seen Feature in [trueCaller](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/truecaller-number-search-spam/id448142450?mt=8). In which When I click `save to contact` button then `iPhone's` default Contact add Screen is opened with Clicked Phone Number. I Searched SO and Web but found only adding via code.

How can I achieve this please assist me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Below iOS 9:**

You can achieve that by using `ABNewPersonViewController` available in the [Addressbook Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1):

```
ABNewPersonViewController *addContactVC = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
addContactVC.newPersonViewDelegate      = self;
UINavigationController *navController   = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addContactVC];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

**iOS 9 or greater:**

You can use `CNContactViewController` of [ContactsUI Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/ContactsUI_Framework/)

```
CNContactViewController *addContactVC = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForNewContact:contact];
addContactVC.delegate                 = self;
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addContactVC];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: @midhumMP thanx it works... What if I want to display a contact by default..Suppose my numbers is 911-099099 when user clicks on it..in Add contact Screen It will show by default

Comment: @RahulMishra: In ABNewPerson set the `displayedPerson` property for that. And in CNContactViewController, use the `contact` property for that. Set those properties with the values that you need to populate