# How to open native add contact interface using ionic/cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

My requirement is to open native add contact interface using ionic.
I googled but could not get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is currently a plugin that will open the add contact interface.

But you could create such a plugin on your own, there is a good tutorial of cordova how a plugin is created:

[Create a Cordova Plugin Tutorial](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/de/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/)

Then you have to find a way how to open the add contact interface. There is a plugin that opens the native settings interface, that will show you how you can do this:

[Open Native Settings iOS](https://github.com/selahssea/Cordova-open-native-settings/blob/master/src/ios/NativeSettings.m)
[Open Native Settings Android](https://github.com/selahssea/Cordova-open-native-settings/blob/master/src/android/NativeSettings.java)

Without testing it I think that will do it for Android:

```
this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI));
```

For iOS it will be a bit more complicated, take a look at this guide:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33887168/6158321

Answer (score 0):

Install Open Native Settings plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/open-native-settings/